# searchkick index related model fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, orm, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a rails application and I'm switching from Sphinx to ElasticSearch and using the gem searchkick.

I have a model Teacher and a model Tags (via a gem), where a Teacher can have multiple tags associated. In the Teacher model I've defined the index like this:

```
def search_data
    {
      name: name,
      intro: intro,
      bio: bio,
      tag_name: tags.name
    }
end
```

Name, intro and bio are Teacher attributes, but I want to index the name od the tags associeted to the teacher. How can I do this?

The way it is now, it indexes the name of the object (relation), how can I index the attribute name inside the tag object?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Shortly after asking the question, I found a solution on one of the issues on the [github page](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/74):

```
def search_data
    {
      name: name,
      intro: intro,
      bio: bio,
      tag_name: tags.map(&:name)
    }
end
```

That indexes the correct attributes.

Comment: Small syntax correction, it should be - `tag_name: tags.map(&:name)`